# What is the optimal mass for deflecting an asteroid?

Tags: forces, mass, velocity, rocket-science, asteroids

What is the optimal weight to launch at an asteroid to deflect it?  Since kinetic energy increases with the square of velocity, it would seem that a very small mass going at a relativistic speed might be optimal for deflecting an asteroid, vs. a larger slower mass.  However, I don't think our current rocket technology can do that.  With current rocket technology, what would be the optimal mass to launch at an asteroid for maximum deflection of the asteroid?

Comment: Since when is F=mv^2 ?

Comment: It appears Kinetic Energy is the term I was looking for: "Translational kinetic energy of a body is equal to one-half the product of its mass, m, and the square of its velocity, v, or 1/2mv2.Aug 20, 2022"
https://www.britannica.com › science

Answer (score 1):

''Because both the needed velocity change and the mass are small, the needed impulse (change in momentum) is so small that deflection can be done by ramming the asteroid with the spacecraft''

It also depends on the mass and how large the asteroid in particular is. Our current rocket technology is enough for atleast knocking it off the course for a bit. For example the knocked Didymos is 780m and the mass is 5,27×10^10 kg. The spacecraft in the dart mission is 676kg wet mass and goes 6,6 km per second. I think you can build your hypothesis from there.